# SQL Server IS_NULLABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Morning,

Just a quick question what this field actually means?

I am trying to create an export script which follows this standard:

```
 lname   varchar(30)     **NOT NULL**,
```

So if last name is_nullable=yes then would I put NULL rather than NOT NULL at the *'d code.

Many Thanks, 
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs for `CREATE TABLE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(SQL.100).aspx) state

```
<column_definition> ::=
column_name <data_type>
    [ FILESTREAM ]
    [ COLLATE collation_name ] 
    [ SPARSE ] 
    [ NULL | NOT NULL ]
    [ 
        [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] DEFAULT constant_expression ] 
      | [ IDENTITY [ ( seed ,increment ) ] [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ] 
    ]
    [ ROWGUIDCOL ] [ <column_constraint> [ ...n ] ]
```

with further explanation

> `NULL | NOT NULL`
>
> Determine whether
>   null values are allowed in the column.
>   NULL is not strictly a constraint but
>   can be specified just like NOT NULL.
>   NOT NULL can be specified for computed
>   columns only if PERSISTED is also
>   specified.

The `[ ]` brackets mean you don't *have to* specify either, but given the complexity of the rules around what the default is (see "Nullability Rules Within a Table Definition" in the above link), you're probably better off always saying which you want.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that :) and everyone that replied.

Answer (score 2):

```
lname   varchar(30)     NOT NULL
```

Means the field lname does not allow NULL values.

```
lname   varchar(30)     NULL
```

On the other hand means that NULL values are allowed.